# I need a sample postgres_exporter.yml file for postgres exporter binary

Tags: postgresql, prometheus-postgres-exporter

I have a running instance of in my local centos/linux environment.

I want to connect this postgres with prometheus using postgres exporter.

The postgres exporter has a flag `--config.file="path-to-config/postgres_exporter.yml"`

I am not able to get `postgres_exporter.yml` file.

Can you please point me to the sample file?

I directly ran

```
% DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/?sslmode=disable"
% ./postgres_exporter
```

It works.

I am expecting:

```
% ./postgres_exporter --config.file="/tmp/postgres_exporter.yml"
```

Comment: There's an example [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter/blob/master/config/testdata/config-good.yaml) and (some) detail on the options [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter#configuration-file).

Answer (score 0):

It's not really stated clearly in [the official github readme](https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter#configuration-file), but it's actually in the auth_modules section.

Alternatively, you can create the *postgres_exporter.yml* file by running the following command:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "auth_modules:
  my_db: # Set this to any name you want
    type: userpass
    userpass:
      username: myusername
      password: mypassword
    options:
      # options become key=value parameters of the DSN
      sslmode: disable
" >> ./postgres_exporter.yml
```